# Plotting a group of pandas dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a few pandas DataFrames that can be thought of as time-points.

They look something like this:

Time 1:

```
pd.DataFrame({'type':[1,2],'b':[200,400]})

    b   type
0   200 1
1   400 2
```

Time 2:

```
pd.DataFrame({'type':[1,4],'b':[100,300]})

    b   type
0   100 1
1   300 4
```

I am trying to combine the DataFrames together and plot them. I am thinking it would be best to plot as a line graph, where data is grouped by the `type` column, and the `b` column is used as the y-axis value.

Comment: what do you mean by combine? x values are the contents of 'type'? do you expect to have one continuous line of many lines overlapping?

Comment: The timepoints will be the x values. And I expect a line for each type.

Comment: there is no timepoint in your example, do you mean the index?

Comment: There are two timepoints in the example, each timepoint being the separate dataframes.

Comment: do your dataframes have a name or order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend a scatter plot that separates values on the type column as different colors and plots along the x axis.

To combine the data-frames, you can use [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html). Assuming your first df is `a` and your second is `b`:

```
df = a.join(b.set_index('b'), on='b')
df.index.name = 'index'  # for plotting as x-axis
```

You can then do the scatter plot:

```
cmap = {0: 'black', 1: 'orchid', 2: 'seagreen', 3: ...}
colors = np.array([cmap[c] for c in df.type])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df.plot.scatter('index', 'type', colors=colors, ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

you can of course choose to do a line plot instead - and let me know if that is really what you want and you can not figure it out from the above example.